# How to turn a text file, into a delimited list of lists

Tags: python

I am attempting to take information from a text file and turn it into a list of lists that I later do more with.
The text file is formatted so that each piece of information is separated by ", " and then at the end of each "person" there is a "\n"
For example,
111, Joe, Jones, 09-01-1980, 10-19-1999, 95000

I am close. But stuck on one small thing.
My current code:

```
def readFile(fileName):
    myFileObj = open(fileName, "r")
    peopleStr = myFileObj.read()
    peopleList = peopleStr.split("\n")
    newPeopleList = []
    for el in peopleList:
        sub = el.split(" ,")
        newPeopleList.append(sub)
    print(newPeopleList)
    
    return newPeopleList
```

This newPeopleList returns

```
[['111, Joe, Jones, 09-01-1980, 10-19-1999, 95000'], ['113, James, Jo, 10-02-1982, 10-18-1998, 85000'], ['123, Jordan, Joul, 08-04-1988, 10-17-1988, 80000']]
```

But what I need is

```
[[111, 'Joe', 'Jones', '09-01-1980', '10-19-1999', 95000], [113, 'James', 'Jo', '10-02-1982', '10-18-1998', 85000], [123, 'Jordan', 'Joul', '08-04-1988', '10-17-1988', 80000]]
```

So they each can be their own item in the list!

I hope this makes some sense, and I appreciate any help!

Comment: You may want to split `el` with `", "` instead of `" ,"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listOfLists = []

with open(filename, "r") as msg:
   for line in msg:
      listOfLists.append(line.strip().replace(" ","").split(","))
   msg.close()
```

This should make it. You read your file line by line, you replace the blank spaces by nothing, you split by "," each line to make a list of it that you store in your list of lists.

Comment: This worked. It makes sense. I was trying to split by "\n" and ", " and I couldn't figure it out. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newlist = [[y.split(", ")] for x in newPeopleList for y in x]
print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get what you want more pythonic:

```
list(map(lambda x:x.split(', '),open(filename,'r').readlines()))
```

you delimiter which is ' ,' in your own code is wrong, while it needs ', '.

Comment: To void the sequence of blank and comma, it should be split(',').replace(' ','') instead of split(', ')